# Python requests.Session implementation with AWS version 4 signing process headers

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, authentication, python-requests, boto3

For communication with AWS API Gateway I've created a `AWSv4SecureSession` class which implements Version 4 Signing Process via inheriting from `requests.Session` and overloading `requests.Session.request()` method. There I add additional header (`Authorization`) required for the authentication.

My question is the following, is there a class in `boto3` or `botocore` modules which I should use instead? What I want is a simple interface [similar](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) to `requests.Session` with `get()`, `post()`, `put()`, `delete()` and `patch()` methods.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod, I should have used that.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [jarmod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271415/jarmod), [aws-requests-auth](https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth) package implements authentication for python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.